# How to make addresses populate from one spreadsheet to another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two excel sheets of store #'s/event details and another one of all the store number addresses. Not every store gets an event so just copying and pasting all the addresses wouldn't be an option. Is there a formula I can put in so all the store numbers used in the events excel can populate out the addresses sitting in the other excel without individually having to copy and paste?

Example:

```
Worksheet A
Store # - 7
Name - Store A
Event Date - Jan 1
Address - blank

Store # - 12
Name - Store B
Event Date - Jan 2


Worksheet B
Store # - 7
Address - 123 Happy St

Store # - 8
Address - 456 Smile Rd

Store # - 9
Address - 987 Tuesday Ln

Store # - 10
Address - 234 Monday Rd

Store # - 11
Address - 456 Wednesday Ln
```

Comment: Try index() & match()  [ref](https://exceljet.net/index-and-match) and share where you get stuck. ( :

Comment: Is your data formatted the same way as your example? If so, reformatting your data into a table is probably a good first step.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the layout of the store list to a simple, flat table with columns for each data item and the store number in the first column, you can use a very simple Vlookup function to look up address, city and any other data you store in that table.

[image]

If cell A1 in Worksheet A contains the store number, then you can use this formula to return the address, the 2nd column in the table. To return the City, change the 2 to a 3.

```
=vlookup(A1,'Worksheet B'!$A$1:$C$4,2,false)
```

Answer (score 0):

First step is probably to get worksheet B in a usable format. The list-type format shown is terrible for processing in a spreadsheet.

If you can't change the format for worksheet B (e.g. by modifying the software generating the list), you can generate a new flat table automatically in a new sheet:

[Screenshot of excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGNJP.png)

Formulas are:

Column E: `=MID(INDIRECT("'Worksheet B'!R"&ROW()*3-5&"C1";FALSE);11;100)`

Column F: `=MID(INDIRECT("'Worksheet B'!R"&ROW()*3-4&"C1";FALSE);11;100)`

Then use VLOOKUP as suggested by Teylyn. Ideally, you should also transform Worksheet A to a table format, which will make it much easier to use VLOOKUP to get the address.